# saving items to local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

In the code I wrote for the dark and light theme, if my body element contains the 'light' class, the local storageme will save it as light. If it doesn't contain 'light' save it as dark and get it. This is how I usually code, but I have trouble saving and importing.

```
function changeLight() {
    lightBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        body.classList.add('light');
        navbar.classList.add('light');
        sideBar.classList.add('light');
               //I cut some places so that it is not crowded
 
    })
}

function changeDark() {
    darkBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        body.classList.remove('light');
        navbar.classList.remove('light');
        sideBar.classList.remove('light');
       //I cut some places so that it is not crowded
    })
}

function setLocalStorage(){
    if(body.classList.contains('light')){
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light')
    } else{
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark')
    }
}

function getLocalStorage(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'light'){
        body.classList.add('light')
    } else{
        body.classList.remove('light')
    }
}

setLocalStorage()
getLocalStorage()

changeLight()
changeDark()
```

Comment: whats the exact problem? and you should fire commands first after page is rendered, it can be that u you act with elements which are not exists durring the run

Comment: you also should save the theme change direct after the change and not doing something like check if something contains a word